# Can't run PHP script accessing my Mysql databse

Tags: networking, server, mysql, php

I've created LAMP server in my ubuntu desktop. I've also made a sample database in Mysql having 6 columns. I can access it through the terminal. I've also created a php script for accessing the same. But when I'm not able to run it in the web browser....

It just shows me a blank page....and nothing else !!!!

Below is my code:

```
// I'd typed http://_MY_IP_ADDRESS_/_FILE_NAME_.php in the browser to run this file

<?php

include('db_login.php');            // include the login info of the user
$connection = mysql_connect($db_host, $db_username, $db_password); // make the connection

if( !$connection )
{
    die("Couldn't connect to the database: <br />", mysql_error());
}    

$db_select = mysql_select_db($db_database);// select the database

if( !$db_select )
{
    die("Couldn't select the database: <br />", mysql_error());
}

// developing the query

$select = 'select';
$coloumn = ' * ';
$from = 'from';
$table = 'table';

$query = $select.$coloumn.$from.$table;                     
$result = mysql_query($query);                          

if( !$query )
{
    die("Couldn't query the database: <br />", mysql_error());
} 

// fetching and displaying the result

while($result_row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
    echo "A".$result_row[1]."<br />";
echo "B".$result_row[2]."<br />";
echo "C".$result_row[3]."<br />";
echo "D".$result_row[4]."<br />";
echo "E".$result_row[5]."<br />";
echo "F".$result_row[6]. "<br /><br />";
}

mysql_close($connection);   
// closing the connection

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Syntax problems on line 8:

```
die("Couldn't connect to the database: <br />", mysql_error());
```

`.` is used as concatenation, not `,`

Same problem on line 15 and 30.

Also, turn on error reporting. To do so:

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);
```

This will turn on all errors.

Comment: Also, the query results will start at `$result_row[0]` not `$result_row[1]` and end at `$result_row[5]`

Comment: Thanks Flukey and douggro for your quick responses....!!!! They solved everything.